# What's the difference between form:select and form:options

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, taglib

I have a naive question, I'm not able to get the difference between the two, from what I see with the generated html both approches result in the same result? Why do we need form:options anyway? An example would be helpful. The spring doc. does not here in explaining the two approches, maybe it relates to basic html structure?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice [example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html)

Essentially form:options tag gives you option to render a part of list you want to display in a drop down a whole of it.
Having the form:select tag gives flexibility to have a combination of option and options tag inside it.
Here is code snippet from the link i have given above.

```
<form:select path="country"> 
 <form:option value="0" label="Select" /> 
 <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="countryId" itemLabel="countryName" /> 
</form:select>
```

Comment: Thats a great example, but how would I get a preselected option using this tag? Say I want label name Russia to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

In spring mvc tag lib `form:select` represent a simple HTML select, while `form:options` permit you to populate a select from items contained in a collection, instead of using several `form:option` tags to do it.

For the `form:select` you have to set the corrisponding path/property of your model class.

For the `form:options` you have to set the list that will populate the select.

Setting the path for your `form:select` tag you will automatically select the option corrisponding to your property value.